# Setting new default audio playback device for ALSA in .asoundrc

Tags: audio, alsa

After looking for a solution for quite some time, I came here to ask. My problem is as follows. Most software can't play any sound. However, there are exceptions, Chrome and Discord can play audio for some reason. I tried to manipulate my `.asoundrc` file and created it with the following contents:

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.pcm.device 3
defaults.timer.card 1

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

pcm.!default "plughw:1,3"

pcm.clone "plughw:1,3"
```

This didn't solve the problem. The `clone` alias was created for testing purposes and yields (for me) uncomprehensible results:

- `aplay -D clone file.wav` plays the specified file as expected,
- `aplay -D plughw:1,3 file.wav` plays the file as expected,
- `aplay -D default file.wav` fails to produce any sound (although the console output is the same as when running the commands above),
- `aplay file.wav` fails to produce any sound.

I tried relogging and rebooting, nothing changed. Alsamixer functions as usual.

Comment: It appears some other configuration file manages to override your `default` device (check `/etc/asound.conf`). Anyway, PulseAudio ignores all that completely.

Comment: There isn't any file at `/etc/asound.conf`. I don't know much about how PulseAudio works, but still I'm convinced at least `aplay -D default ...` should function properly.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem by installing pavucontrol and manipulating the settings there - `aplay` now plays sound as it should. I will test other software now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve my problems. I needed to install `pavucontrol`, add the correct device to PulseAudio's list of available sinks, then set the newly added sink (generated from an ALSA device) as the default one for PulseAudio. That fixed the problem.